# How can I read the contents of a file in a GCP bucket?

Tags: python, arrays, string, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I need to read the first 20 lines of a file that is currently inside a GCP bucket.  I am trying to read the contents of a file through a Google Function with an HTTP trigger.  I can get to the file, but when I try to return the contents by using "return data_string", so that I can see the output, it doesn't work.  I don't have to return the entire contents of that file, that's why I only need the first 20 lines.  Ideally, I'd like some command to read the contents and grab each line of the file and add it to an array, which I could then grab specific lines from.  If I do this on my development PC with the same file that's also in the Google bucket and use the open() command, it works just fine.  I can read every line and grab what I want, but I need to test it through a Google Function.  Please help!

Here is the code I have so far.

```
 storage_client = storage.Client()
    #define bucket
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    
    #Blob: File name that will be saved.
    blob = bucket.get_blob('LAS.las')
    data_string = blob.download_as_string()
    print(data_string)
return data_string
```

Comment: What means `doesn't works`?

Comment: if you have text file then `data_string.split('\n')[:20]` and you have 20 lines. If you have small file then it can be faster to read all file at once (which need only one request to server) then reading line by line (which may need many requests to server).

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add this, but then I got the error below.  Do I need to convert it first?

data_split = data_string.split('\n')[:20] 
return data_split[0]

line 35, in hello_world 
data_split = data_string.split('\n')[:20] 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: maybe it gives bytes data and you have to `decode()` it  before split `data_string.decode().split('\n')[:20]`. BTW: if you use `[0]` in `return data_split[0]` then you get only first line. if you need 20 lines then you need `return data_split` without `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need 20 lines then you could split string to lines using `.split('\n')` and then you can use `[:20]` to get 20 lines.

It seems `download_as_string()` gives `bytes` which you have to convert to `unicode` using `decode()` or `decode('utf-8')` if you want to make sure it will use `utf-8` or ie. `decode('cp1250')` if you have text in encoding `cp1250`

```
blob = bucket.get_blob('LAS.las')
data_string = blob.download_as_string()

# convert bytes to unicode
data_string = data_string.decode()  

# convert string to list of lines
lines = data_string.split('\n')  

# return first 20 lines
return lines[:20]
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, it didn't work.  I just tried it and got this error:

data_string = data_string.decode() UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2291: invalid start byte

Would this mean that I'm using the wrong parameter for decoding it?

Comment: check in Google what char may have code `0xb0` and in what encoding - maybe it is `cp1250` or `iso-8858` (both popular on Windows)  But endoding is only for raw text file and I see extension `.las` first time and I don't know if can be not text file.

Comment: more codecs in python documentation [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) but if `.las` is not raw text file but compressed or with special structure then encoding makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.  I did notice that when it's in the bucket, it says "application/octet-stream" under the "Type" column.  Does that help to figure out how what to use?

Comment: it can meas it is not text file or it is file with compressed text or with text keep in special way and you need special function to extract text from file. For example files like `.txt` you can read without any special methods but `.doc`, `.xls`, `.pdf` (which also may keep text) you can't read without special methods.

Comment: OK, as a test I uploaded a text file named "test.txt" and it was created with Notepad.  It contains just a whole bunch of random words.  I ran the decode on it with 'utf_8', but I'm getting this error, does that mean the decoding work and now it's another problem?

The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you get in lines. it seems you get strings but now you have different problem. You run it probably in Django view function - but Django expects that it will return `string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable` which it know how to use to create HTML for web browser - but you return `list` (list of lines). You may generate `string` (`"".join(lines[:20])`) or `tuple` (`tuple(lines[:20])`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to use print().  I did this code, but when I ran the function, the website just shows "OK".  Sorry, I am trying to show the code properly, but I'm not sure how to do it so it shows properly.

data_string = data_string.decode('utf_8')
    # convert string to list of lines
    lines = data_string.split('\n')
    print(lines)

Comment: `print()` is not to display it on webside but to see text/values in console/terminal - but it means you have to start code in  console/terminal

Comment: Thought so!  I can use print() in the local Python script i have on my computer, but if I can't use print() on the website, what else can I use to print it out?  I know the code works when I ran it againt the LAS. las file and I could extract any line from it.

Comment: if you run code on server and you didn't start it manually in console/terminal on server then you can - add values to HTML which servers sends to browser OR save result in file/log to see it later when you download file/log to local computer.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I finally figured out that the decode value was indeed cp1250 and that I couldn't return an array from the function.  I instead created a string based on what I could extract from the file, after I finally decoded it, and then I was able to return that string to the website.  Now I can see exactly the lines I wanted to get from the file and I can go ahead with the next step of my task.  Again, thanks a lot for your help!